# DefaultTableModel en Jtable Java

Tags: java

Tengo una tabla en la cual quiero insertar los datos de unos clientes.

¿Por qué me da error el **DefaultTableModel**, diciéndome el siguiente error?

**Error:**

```
ArrayList<Object> cannot be converted to int
```

**Código:**

```
import bbdd.Conexiones;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class Listado_clientes extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    private DefaultTableModel dtm;

    public Listado_clientes() {
        initComponents();

        //Creamos un array llamado "listadoclientes" que tendrá los datos de listado_clientes().
        ArrayList<Object> listadoclientes = new ArrayList<Object>();
        listadoclientes = Conexiones.listado_clientes();

        //Fila de los títulos de la tabla.
        String[] titulos = {"DNI", "NOMBRE", "APELLIDOS", "TELEFONO", "DIRECCION", "CIUDAD", "EMAIL"};

        tabla_clientes.setModel(dtm);
        //Agregamos al objeto de tipo DefaultTableModel "dtm" los parámetros necesarios.
        dtm = new DefaultTableModel(listadoclientes, titulos);
        //Añadimos los datos del "dtm" a la tabla "tabla_clientes".
        tabla_clientes.setModel(dtm);

        //tabla.getColumnModel().getColumn(model.findColumn("NombreColumna")).setPreferredWidth(tamaño);
        tabla_clientes.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(260);
        tabla_clientes.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(160);
        tabla_clientes.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setPreferredWidth(150);
        tabla_clientes.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setPreferredWidth(180);
        tabla_clientes.getColumnModel().getColumn(4).setPreferredWidth(160);
        tabla_clientes.getColumnModel().getColumn(5).setPreferredWidth(140);
        tabla_clientes.getColumnModel().getColumn(6).setPreferredWidth(140);
    }
}
```

**listado_clientes():**

```
   public static ArrayList listado_clientes() {
        ArrayList<Cliente> clientes = new ArrayList<Cliente>();
        String bbdd = Conexiones.bbdd;
        Connection c = (Connection) Conexiones.conexion_a_BBDD(bbdd);
        Statement stm;
        ResultSet rs;
        try {
            //Consulta para sacar todos los datos de la tabla "clientes".
            stm = c.createStatement();
            String consulta_clientes = "SELECT * FROM clientes ORDER BY apellidos, nombre;";
            rs = stm.executeQuery(consulta_clientes);
            //System.out.println("CONSULTA TODOS LOS CLIENTES: Mostramos todos los clientes de la tabla 'clientes'.");
            while (rs.next()) {
                Cliente cliente = new Cliente();
                cliente.setNombre(rs.getString("nombre")); 
                cliente.setApellidos(rs.getString("apellidos")); 
                cliente.setDNI(rs.getString("DNI")); 
                cliente.setTelefono(rs.getString("telefono"));
                cliente.setDireccion(rs.getString("direccion")); 
                cliente.setCiudad(rs.getString("ciudad")); 
                cliente.setEmail(rs.getString("email")); 
                clientes.add(cliente);  
            }
            c.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        for(int i=0;i<clientes.size();i++){
            System.out.println(clientes.get(i));
        }      
        return clientes;
    }
```

Comment: La clase `DefaultTableModel` no tiene ningún constructor que espere como parámetros `ArrayList, String[]`

Comment: ¿Debo crear un constructor para que los reciba o es inviable esa opción? @E.Betanzos

Comment: No puedes creer un constructor en una clase del API de Java

Comment: @E.Betanzos Entonces solución errónea. Deberé crear un Object en vez de ArrayList y recorrerlo... intuyo.

Comment: El constructor para pasar parámetros al modelo es [este](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html#DefaultTableModel(java.lang.Object[][],%20java.lang.Object[]))

Comment: ¿Cuál sería una posible solución? ¿Tendría que cambiar el método listado_clientes y cambiar el ArrayList por un Object[][]? @E.Betanzos